# Permission not granted for creating file in /home

Tags: command-line, sudo, home-directory

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to create a new dir in `/home`, lets call it `myDir`, and then I want to create a `.txt` file that outputs the current date. All these through terminal comands. So, to be more specific... I am in `/home` and I type

```
sudo -l #So I can type comands as superuser, I think.
sudo -mkdir myDir #That works fine, the new directory is created, but
```

then.

```
sudo date > myDir/output.txt
```

It still does not give me any permission.

Someone might wonder, "You really have to create a new dir in /home?", well to tell you the truth, yes I do! Its a step from a school exercise and I am also really curious. I'am telling you so far I love ubuntu (installed 3 days ago) and if I can manage to fix a problem with my internet connection (one issue at a time) I am so gonna delete windows from my laptop!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm reasonably certain your school exercise meant you to use *your* home directory, not `/home`.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I am a super noob! I meant home directory!

Comment: Then you want something like `/home/skemelio`, or `~`, or `$HOME`. The terminal opens to your home directory by default. No `sudo` required.

Comment: That would really make sense, but the professor's orders are clear. He wants a new directory in home. If that is not possible then its ok... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Unless he specifically said `/home` with a `/` at the beginning, you are misunderstanding him.

Comment: You can create a new user and you will get folder with that username.  And inside YOUR home folder (/home/your_name/) you can create any folder without "sudo".  If I need to create some folders with administrator permission (rarely), I use "sudo nautilus",  and I modify folders in Files application.

Answer (score 2):

Your home directory means $HOME which is actually /home/username .
You cannot write to /home because it is a system folder which you do not have the rights to modify .